# autofill form field based on another field's data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with `scriptcase`, a php code generator. I have a search form with 4 search fields depending on each others data. What I want to achieve is the following:

- If the user selects the `state` in the first field, the second field should be auto-filled with the `cities` of that `state`.
- After the `city` is chosen the third field to be automatically filled with the `schools` in that city.

All my data is stored in one single table in the database. I'm using `PHP` and `MySQL`.

Any help, tip or direction is greatly appreciated!

Thank you all!

Mirela

Comment: @Glavic are you serious?

Comment: @Glavić Hahahahahaha... What will be ratio of such people now a days who dont have JS installed on their machines?

Comment: @Glavić you are so complicated :)

Comment: JS would be my salvation ..but unfortunaly scriptcase isn't that good to programmers. It doesn't allow me to add as much code as i need, limiting me in a small range of prebuild functions (whom i dont need for this case)! .. still looking for a solution..and time's running out :( thank you all for the time and consideration!!!

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this solution but we will take in consideration that we can't include other php file in scriptcase...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
        {
        $("#monedha").change(function()            
        {
        var val=$(this).val();
        var dataString="&val="+val;


//var dataString= fatura_file;
        $.ajax
        ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "modules.php?name=Expenses_2&file=get_monedha_ajax",              
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
        $("#select_tr").empty();    
        $("#select_tr").append(html);   
        }
        });
        });
        });
        </script>
      <?php  
        echo "<td align='right' width='50%' nowrap>Monedha:</td>";
        echo "<td align='left' colspan='3'>";
        echo "<select name='monedha' id='monedha'>";
        echo "<option value='ALL' selected >Lek</option>";
        echo "<option value='EUR' $ee>Euro</option>";
        echo "<option value='USD' $eu>USD</option>";
        echo "<option value='GBP' $eg>GBP</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr bgcolor='$bgcol[0]'>";
        echo "<td align='right' width='50%'>Llogaria:</td>";        
        echo "<td align='left' colspan='3'>";   
        if($error[11]) echo "<b><font color='red'>Please select Llogaria!</font></b><br>";
        echo "<div >";  
        $kat = $db->sql_query("SELECT * FROM nuke_banks WHERE monedha='lek' OR monedha='ALL'");
        echo "<select name='lloji' id='select_tr'>";
        while($r = $db->sql_fetchrow($kat))
                    {
                    echo "<option value='".$r['id']."'>&nbsp; - ".$r['emer']."</option>";                
                    }
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</div>";
        ?>
```

And here is the php file`modules.php?name=Expenses_2&file=get_monedha_ajax` which is used to call the content of second drop down :

```
if( isset($_GET['val'])){
$kat = $db->sql_query("SELECT * FROM banks $_GET['val']");
    while($r = $db->sql_fetchrow($kat))
                {
                echo "<option value=".$r['id'].">&nbsp; - ".$r['emer']."</option>";              
                }
 }
```

I don't know it it can be used that way in scriptcase...
Note: this is not a scriptcase code. It's just an example

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be completely solved from within Scriptcase.

Taking the States and Cities as an example. Assuming these are fields called state_id and city_id respectively.

In the state_id field check the Ajax processing box and choose to refresh the city_id field.

In the city_id field set the select statement to be

```
    SELECT city_id,city_name
    FROM city_list
    WHERE state_id = {state_id}
```

You should now find that selecting the state will refresh the city list. You can repeat and cascade this process through as many levels as you wish. It is helpful in most cases to set "Use title" to *Yes* so that you get a blank line at the top of the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

When the user select state onselect of the state call an ajax function which returns the cities of that state and populate the firld with cities, on selecting a city call another ajax which returns the schools in that city and so on...

If you tried anything with code post it I can help you

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good article describing exactly the solution to your problem [here](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html).

This article populates cities based on selected state and states based on selected country. All these three fields are dropdown lists filled with data from a DB and of course the implementation utilizes [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

The only drawback of this implementation is that the writer uses `mysql_*` which is deprecated. Instead try to use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: You know you could at least add some basics instead of just giving a link, you can add that link too, but what if that link get's deleted? Your answer will be null.

Comment: I just gave a point which the OP can start reading through and come back (after implementing the basics) when stuck. Then we can assist further based on specific input. Besides if the references were considered _invalid_ or _inappropriate_ then half of the answers here should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking 2 questions:

1. How can I update *input b* if *input* a changes
2. On *input b* I want to have a autocomplete box.

   - 1: I would suggest looking at [knoutoutjs library](http://knockoutjs.com/), it gives you a nice interface for building **mvvm models** in javascript.
   - 2: I would suggest looking at the autocomplete box of jquery, here is a [nice live example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Answer (score 0):

```
function search(){
    $q=$_GET["entry"];
    $b=array();
    $a;  //get your database values to variable a;
    if (strlen($q) > 0){
        $lq=strtolower($q);
        for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++){
            $la=strtolower($a[$i]->state);  
            if ((substr_count($la,$lq))>0){
                $b[]=$a[$i]->state;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count($b)==0){
        $response="no name exits with ". "<b>".$q."</b>";
        echo $response;
    } else {
        $response=json_encode($b);
        echo $response;
    }
}
```

this is code for search with database values after ajax call now in first page put this for a ajax call and to build select box with ajax

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function showhint(str){
                if (str.length==0){
                    document.getElementById("create").innerHTML="";
                    return;
                }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    hint=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    obj=eval('('+hint+')');
                var create = '<select>';
                for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
                    create += '<option>'+obj[i]+'</option>';
                }
                create += '</select>';
                }
                    jQuery('#create').html(create);
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?entry="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        country name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showhint(this.value)" size="20" />
        <br><br>
        <span id="show"></span>
   </body>
</html>
```

in the second code i made country name as text i think you are using it as select box your logic may vary from calling function onkeyup to onselect and database records to $a in accordance with country name